# How to delete files after X number of days

Tags: mysql, cron

I have had a long standing script over 5 years preparing a daily backup of MySQL databases in a directory on the server. I want to know how to automatically delete files older than 90 days. Here is my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

uname=XXXX
upass=XXX
dbprefix="/home2/XXX/DatabaseBackups"

for db in $(echo -e "show schemas like \"XXXX%\";" | mysql -u $uname -p$upass -N)
do
wget -q -nv -P ${dbprefix} --http-user=${uname} --http-password=${upass} --auth-no-challenge http://localhost:2082/getsqlbackup/${db}.sql.gz
done
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
find /pathtofiles/ -type f -mtime +90 -name '*.sql.gz' -execdir rm -- '{}' \;
```

also  something like  this should work too

```
find /pathtofiles/ -name '*.sql.gz' -mindepth 1 -mtime +90 -delete
```

Comment: Yes. But be _really, really careful_ when using `find -delete` or the like.

Comment: One should test the `find` command with the `-print` command instead of `-delete`, then `find` simply shows the filenames it would delete.

Comment: OK, thanks. So I can add one of the code suggestions above and it should execute? Do I need to specify a variable anywhere else? (New to the programming scene).

Comment: with  find + delete  script  most important  thing is to  be sure that you have correct  paths.  In my scripts  i have  all variables  inside scripts (this way  i know  where to find them )